# calendar app using calendar.instance()

Tags: android, calendar

using this [link](http://www.technotalkative.com/android-get-current-date-and-time-in-different-format/) i followed the tutorial on getting the current date and time but im getting error on instance part of calendar..do i need to add other code for this or this is not working anymore so i search and found this code and this is what i am using now its month is wrong and so is the year.

```
Date d=new Date(); 
                int a=d.getDate();
                int b=d.getMonth();
                int c=d.getYear();
                int f=d.getHours();
                int e=d.getMinutes();
```

i want to make my own calendar so i wanted to use the calendar.instance() thing seeing that is the most appropriate but its not working
[image]
[image]

Comment: @iamafresher updated the question with a printscreen

Comment: I think problem is with import

Comment: @iamafresher please look at update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you already used the reference `c` at this scope for naming `int` variable, so you should change `Calendar c` to something else. Secondly, you have you own class `Calendar`, that is why it intersects with `Calendar` from `java.util`. I recommend you to rename your class `Calendar` to something like `MyCalendar`, or you can use fully-qualified names. Also `import` statements should be at the top of file.

Answer (score 0):

use the line   `Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();` instead of   C`alendar c= Calendar.getInstance();`

you already used the reference **c**, so use a new reference!! and work accordingly with `cal` in place of reference `c`

also look for imports for Calendaruse `import java.util.Calendar;`

also give full qualified name as `java.util.Calendar  cal =  java.util.Calendar.getInstance();`

Comment: same error happens The method getInstance() is undefined for the type Calendar..i think im missing something here

Comment: please remove yours all imports and use the import line as import java.util.Calendar;

Comment: also showing one quick fix, what it is... look and work with this as well

Comment: its funny but i remove all import but the import you gave me give error..i update the question can you take a look

Comment: quick fix says remove the import you told me to put which should i follow then?im sorry im new in programming just following tutorial to learn..

Comment: than use as follows java.util.Calendar  cal =  java.util.Calendar.getInstance();